# Is there any way I can get key from values in python?(dictionary)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

This question seem abit weird as I know dictionary are not intended to be used based on values rather than keys I recently came across certain problem to minimize the form fill up procedure as If certain country cities are provided then I need to autocomplete  country and continent for that user.
I got following Json for my reference .

```
[{
        "Asia": {
            "Japan": [
                "tokyo",
                "hirohima",
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Europe": {
            "England": [
                "Manchester",
                "London",
                "South gate",
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Suppose user City is London Can I get England and Europe as Output? or Is my json formating wrong?

Comment: Sure - you'll just have to iterate over those dicts and find the list where the city you're want is.

Comment: Assumnig the values are hashable, you can run through the data once and create a reverse index. There is a complication because the value may be in more than one dictionary. For instance, London Ontario. Not sure how you want to deal with that.

Comment: You may not need that outer list. In your example, it only has a single value, the dict with asia and europe in it.

Comment: @tdelaney - Outer list has 2 dictionaries. One with key "Asia" and one with key "Europe"

Comment: @not_speshal - oh, right. So the question is why the dicts with only a single value in them.

Comment: @tdelaney - This is a very typical json structure.

Comment: [Convert the json to xml](https://pypi.org/project/json2xml/), then use xpath/dom to get all the relevant ancestors.

Comment: @not_speshal - OP asked "is my json formatting wrong". I suggested that the outer list may be redundant as all of the information could be in a single dict. By putting it into a list, the consumer of the data is always tasked with merging the interior dicts in some manner. I don't care if its normal so much as if its necessary to push that onto the consumer.

Comment: This is likely a snapshot of the actual data. OP probably has multiple countries for each continent. So this structure would be necessary.

Comment: This structure means you can't do simple look ups like `data["Asia"]["Japan"]`. Multiple countries for each continent should just be multiple items in the continent dict. Maybe OP is using some tool set that generates data this way, but Its better to do the merge close to the data so that you don't have merge code scattered all over the place.

Comment: these is a very huge data that will come from selenium scraping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the data and "reverse engineer" the dictionary:

```
city = "London"
for d in data:
    for continent, countries in d.items():
        for country, cities in countries.items():
            if "London" in cities:
                print(country, continent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a reverse index of city to country/region tuples. Since city names are not unique, you may have the same city name in multiple countries. You could solve this by indexing to a list of country/regions. You would do this once when you get the data and then its available for quick lookup when needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{
        "Asia": {
            "Japan": [
                "tokyo",
                "hirohima",
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Europe": {
            "England": [
                "Manchester",
                "London",
                "South gate",
            ]
        }
    }
]

reverse_index = defaultdict(list)

for region_dict in data:
    for region, country_dict in region_dict.items():
        for country, city_list in country_dict.items():
            for city in city_list:
                reverse_index[city].append((region, country))
            
for city, refs in reverse_index.items():
    print(city, refs)
```

Answer (score 1):

to get country name and continent name your json file must be in this form :

```
[{"ContinentName":"Asia","country":{"countryName":"Japan","cities":["tokyo","hirohima"]}},{"ContinentName":"Europe","country":{"countryName":"England","cities":["london","south gate","Manchester"]}}]
```

Comment: thank you for ans for this was not primary question asked by me

Comment: it is better to change json form , if you want later to convert json file to list of object